# ID parameter missing from URL string, using Angular factory module to pass to ruby backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

My current mini project is using ruby/ruby on rails on the backend and angular on the front end.  I have a function which is accessing a method in my ruby backend via an angular factory injection but my current error keeps saying:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/api/examples/add_example”):
```

Now I know one of the immediate problems is that the URL route itself is missing the id parameter and should look something like this:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/api/examples/1/add_example”):
```

I have tried looking at my code to understand why the id parameter is not being fed in but cannot work it out.

This is my code-

This is my function in my examplesShow controller which talks to the factory route:

```
examplesShowController.$inject = ['example', '$state', 'User'];
function examplesShowController(example, $state, User) {
 const examplesShow = this;

 examplesShow.example = example.get($state.params);

 examplesShow.example.$addexample(() => {
  $state.reload();
  console.log('click');
 })
}
```

This is my factory module which passes from the controller function to the backend:

```
angular.module('Project')
 .factory('example', example);

example.$inject = ['$resource', 'API_URL'];
function example($resource, API_URL) {
 return new $resource(`${API_URL}/examples/:id`, { id: '@_id' }, {
  update: { method: 'PUT' },
  addexample: { method: 'POST', url: `${API_URL}/examples/:id/add_example` }
 });
}
```

This is my routes to allow the factory url to communicate to the backend:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

 scope :api do
  resources :examples
  resources :users, except: [:create]
  post 'examples/:id/add_example', to: 'examples#add_example'
  post 'register', to: 'auth#register'
  post 'login', to: 'auth#login'
 end
end
```

My routes & factory route looks configured correctly however, struggling to understand why the error no route matching is still persisting and most importantly why the 'id' parameter is missing from the URL despite clearly having it in my routes.

Any light shed on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`rake routes` will tell you what urls you have in your Rails app. From there you'll have a better idea what is going wrong.

Comment: thanks for this Thomas...still no luck..think the problem is in the object of the addExample function - I'm missing grabbing the id when returning the object from the state params...